# CountdownTimer not getting Cancelled

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

So I looked at so many sources and whenever there is such a problem, it's because the countdowntimer is trying to get cancelled from inside the ontick. This is not my issue. I have the countdowntimer in a runnable. I cancel the timer, I cancel the runnable and it still somehow gets called. Here is some code below. I appreciate any help!

```
Handler myHandler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        CountDownTimer countdownTimer = new CountDownTimer(difference - (1000 * 60) + 2000, 60000) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {          // some work here
            }
            public void onFinish() {
            // some other work here
        };
        data.get(i).setCountDownTimer(countdownTimer);
        data.get(i).getCountDownTimer().start();
    }
};
data.get(i).setHandler(myHandler);
data.get(i).setRunnable(runnable);
data.get(i).start(2000);
```

The start function is basically:

```
public void start(int milliseconds){
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, milliseconds);
}
```

data is just a list of objects where each has its own runnable, handler and countdowntimer.

Here is what I do when I cancel:

```
 data.get(i).getCountDownTimer().cancel();
 data.get(i).terminate();
```

The terminate function is basically:

```
public void terminate() {
      handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
}
```

Someone please tell me why the countdowntimer somehow still runs after I cancel it the way I do above; thanks!

**UPDATE**

In onFinish, I have another countdown that is on a smaller interval. Is onFinish called when I cancel a CountDownTimer? Otherwise I'm really out of ideas! Thanks.

Comment: `cancel()` should be enough. How do you get to know, that the CDT is still running?

Comment: @injecteer Because onTick still gets called after I cancel..

Answer (score 0):

Although you made a good effort to post the relevant pieces of your code, I'm having a hard time imagining how they all fit together.  For example, when you create the `Runnable` for each data object, are the calls to set and start the countdown timer really in the `run()` method as shown?  I'm wondering how `data` and `i` are accessible at that point. And if they are truly accessible, how you know that `i` will have the desired value when the `Runnable` comes out of the queue and executes?

I agree that cancel() should cause the `CountDownTimer` to stop.  Note however that if `start()` is called after `cancel()` the timer will start anew--it's not a one-shot. If a bug is causing `start()` to be called a second time, it will look like the cancel didn't work.

All I can suggest is that you add a bunch of `Log` statements throughout your code to confirm your assumptions about when timers are starting and being cancelled, and what the value of `i` is for each instance.

Answer (score 0):

This was a very silly mistake on my end. When I was removing an object from the data list, I was cancelling the alarm via:
 data.get(i).getCountDownTimer().cancel();
And then I remove the object, and notifyitemremoved. The mistake is that I should notifyitemchanged, and in the onbind, I should cancel it. Then I should remove the entry safely knowing the CTD has been cancelled. Anyway, thanks everyone for the input.